# How to fetch multiple groupby in laravel blade?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, eloquent, laravel-8

Hello i have a result like this [image: laravel array result from groupby(['date', 'project_site_id'])] it is group by date and id. Now my problem is how can i fetch this kind of array in laravel blade i try my best but no luck. i try foreach but it is giving me wrong result? Below is my code

```
$current_date = Carbon::parse(date('Y-m-d'));

$data = EmployeeActivities::where('date', '>=', $current_date->startOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d'))->where('date', '<=', $current_date->endOfWeek()->format('Y-m-d'))->get()->groupBy(['date', 'project_site_id']);

foreach($data as $key => $value){
        //echo $key;
        foreach($value as $key_nested => $value1){
            foreach($value1 as $key_nested1){
                echo $key_nested1.'</br></br>';
            }
        }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's cast `\Illuminate\Support\Collection` to array and this should work.
`$employeeActivitiesData = $data->toArray();`